# multiplication with *=

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

I have an array with these values:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => int 1
      1 => float 0.125
      2 => float 0.5
      3 => float 3
  1 => 
    array
      1 => int 1
      2 => float 5
      3 => float 7
      0 => float 8
  2 => 
    array
      2 => int 1
      3 => float 3
      0 => float 2
      1 => float 0.2
  3 => 
    array
      3 => int 1
      0 => float 0.33333333333333
      1 => float 0.14285714285714
      2 => float 0.33333333333333
```

And i want for each group the multiplication of each row like:

```
1*0.125*05*3
```

I am trying this code:

```
$final= array_fill(0, count($matrix), 0);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matrix); $i++) {
    $a = 1;
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($matrix)-1; $j++) {
        $final[$i] *= $matrix[$i][$j]*$matrix[$i][$a];
        $a++;
    }
}
```

but i got 0 for each multiplication row.

The code works well with +=, but:

```
1*0.125*05*3 = 0.1875 (this is the objective)
```

is different of

```
1*0.125+0.125*0.5+*0.5*3 = 16875
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not just do

```
$final = array();
foreach( $matrix as $arr ) {
    $final[] = array_product( $arr );
}

print_r( $final );
```

Which results in

```
Array ( [0] => 0.1875 [1] => 280 [2] => 1.2 [3] => 0.015873015873015 )
```

Alternatively, if you want to continue to do it your way:

```
$final= array_fill(0, count($matrix), 1);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matrix); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($matrix); $j++) {
        $final[$i] *= $matrix[$i][$j];
    }
}
```

I removed the `-1` because that meant it missed the last element take `1*5*8*7` for example. Your way `= 40` because the `7` was never multiplied. The above outputs the same result.

Comment: No problem. Also added a version of your code which outputs the same result but isn't as readable imo :)

Answer (score 1):

The neutral element for the multiplication is 1, not 0. You're filling your final array with zeros with this statement

```
$final= array_fill(0, count($matrix), 0);
```

and, obviously, when you do

```
$final[$i] *= $matrix[$i][$j];
```

everything will be zero as well. Thus, you have to replace the first line with this one:

```
$final= array_fill(0, count($matrix), 1);
```

Comment: yes, works, but there is another error probably. For example 8*1*5*7 should be 280 and i got 1400.

Comment: @loops Because every time in the J-loop you multiply 3 numbers that probably is not what you want. Get rid of one of the two elements on the right of *=

Answer (score 0):

0 * anything is 0. You initialized your array to all 0.